# The markup in the document following the root element must be well-formed- Netbeans and XML

Tags: java, xml, netbeans

Hello  I ve got this xml file, and this error: **The markup in the document following the root element must be well-formed.** Please help.
P.S With another xml file i have no problems. I need this file to use it in agent program.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
    <pozycja>
        <nazwa_waluty>dolar amerykanski</nazwa_waluty>
        <przelicznik>1</przelicznik>
        <kod_waluty>USD</kod_waluty>
        <kurs_sredni>3,8741</kurs_sredni>
    </pozycja>
    <pozycja>
        <nazwa_waluty>dolar australijski</nazwa_waluty>
        <przelicznik>1</przelicznik>
        <kod_waluty>AUD</kod_waluty>
        <kurs_sredni>2,9067</kurs_sredni>
    </pozycja>
    <pozycja>
        <nazwa_waluty>dolar Hongkongu</nazwa_waluty>
        <przelicznik>1</przelicznik>
        <kod_waluty>HKD</kod_waluty>
        <kurs_sredni>0,4994</kurs_sredni>
    </pozycja>
    <pozycja>
        <nazwa_waluty>dolar kanadyjski</nazwa_waluty>
        <przelicznik>1</przelicznik>
        <kod_waluty>CAD</kod_waluty>
        <kurs_sredni>3,0337</kurs_sredni>
    </pozycja>
    <pozycja>
        <nazwa_waluty>dolar nowozelandzki</nazwa_waluty>
        <przelicznik>1</przelicznik>
        <kod_waluty>NZD</kod_waluty>
        <kurs_sredni>2,7713</kurs_sredni>
    </pozycja>
    <pozycja>
        <nazwa_waluty>dolar singapurski</nazwa_waluty>
        <przelicznik>1</przelicznik>
        <kod_waluty>SGD</kod_waluty>
        <kurs_sredni>2,8919</kurs_sredni>
    </pozycja>
    <pozycja>
        <nazwa_waluty>euro</nazwa_waluty>
        <przelicznik>1</przelicznik>
        <kod_waluty>EUR</kod_waluty>
        <kurs_sredni>4,3935</kurs_sredni>
    </pozycja>
    <pozycja>
        <nazwa_waluty>forint (Wegry)</nazwa_waluty>
        <przelicznik>100</przelicznik>
        <kod_waluty>HUF</kod_waluty>
        <kurs_sredni>1,4023</kurs_sredni>
    </pozycja>
    <pozycja>
        <nazwa_waluty>frank szwajcarski</nazwa_waluty>
        <przelicznik>1</przelicznik>
        <kod_waluty>CHF</kod_waluty>
        <kurs_sredni>4,0380</kurs_sredni>
    </pozycja>
    <pozycja>
        <nazwa_waluty>funt szterling</nazwa_waluty>
        <przelicznik>1</przelicznik>
        <kod_waluty>GBP</kod_waluty>
        <kurs_sredni>5,7200</kurs_sredni>
    </pozycja>
    <pozycja>
        <nazwa_waluty>hrywna (Ukraina)</nazwa_waluty>
        <przelicznik>1</przelicznik>
        <kod_waluty>UAH</kod_waluty>
        <kurs_sredni>0,1557</kurs_sredni>
    </pozycja>
    <pozycja>
        <nazwa_waluty>jen (Japonia)</nazwa_waluty>
        <przelicznik>100</przelicznik>
        <kod_waluty>JPY</kod_waluty>
        <kurs_sredni>3,7101</kurs_sredni>
    </pozycja>
    <pozycja>
        <nazwa_waluty>korona czeska</nazwa_waluty>
        <przelicznik>1</przelicznik>
        <kod_waluty>CZK</kod_waluty>
        <kurs_sredni>0,1623</kurs_sredni>
    </pozycja>
    <pozycja>
        <nazwa_waluty>korona dunska</nazwa_waluty>
        <przelicznik>1</przelicznik>
        <kod_waluty>DKK</kod_waluty>
        <kurs_sredni>0,5908</kurs_sredni>
    </pozycja>
    <pozycja>
        <nazwa_waluty>korona islandzka</nazwa_waluty>
        <przelicznik>100</przelicznik>
        <kod_waluty>ISK</kod_waluty>
        <kurs_sredni>3,1653</kurs_sredni>
    </pozycja>
    <pozycja>
        <nazwa_waluty>korona norweska</nazwa_waluty>
        <przelicznik>1</przelicznik>
        <kod_waluty>NOK</kod_waluty>
        <kurs_sredni>0,4696</kurs_sredni>
    </pozycja>
    <pozycja>
        <nazwa_waluty>korona szwedzka</nazwa_waluty>
        <przelicznik>1</przelicznik>
        <kod_waluty>SEK</kod_waluty>
        <kurs_sredni>0,4717</kurs_sredni>
    </pozycja>
    <pozycja>
        <nazwa_waluty>kuna (Chorwacja)</nazwa_waluty>
        <przelicznik>1</przelicznik>
        <kod_waluty>HRK</kod_waluty>
        <kurs_sredni>0,5845</kurs_sredni>
    </pozycja>
    <pozycja>
        <nazwa_waluty>lej rumunski</nazwa_waluty>
        <przelicznik>1</przelicznik>
        <kod_waluty>RON</kod_waluty>
        <kurs_sredni>0,9691</kurs_sredni>
    </pozycja>
    <pozycja>
        <nazwa_waluty>lew (Bulgaria)</nazwa_waluty>
        <przelicznik>1</przelicznik>
        <kod_waluty>BGN</kod_waluty>
        <kurs_sredni>2,2464</kurs_sredni>
    </pozycja>
    <pozycja>
        <nazwa_waluty>lira turecka</nazwa_waluty>
        <przelicznik>1</przelicznik>
        <kod_waluty>TRY</kod_waluty>
        <kurs_sredni>1,3372</kurs_sredni>
    </pozycja>
    <pozycja>
        <nazwa_waluty>nowy izraelski szekel</nazwa_waluty>
        <przelicznik>1</przelicznik>
        <kod_waluty>ILS</kod_waluty>
        <kurs_sredni>1,0029</kurs_sredni>
    </pozycja>
    <pozycja>
        <nazwa_waluty>peso chilijskie</nazwa_waluty>
        <przelicznik>100</przelicznik>
        <kod_waluty>CLP</kod_waluty>
        <kurs_sredni>0,5718</kurs_sredni>
    </pozycja>
    <pozycja>
        <nazwa_waluty>peso filipinskie</nazwa_waluty>
        <przelicznik>1</przelicznik>
        <kod_waluty>PHP</kod_waluty>
        <kurs_sredni>0,0836</kurs_sredni>
    </pozycja>
    <pozycja>
        <nazwa_waluty>peso meksykanskie</nazwa_waluty>
        <przelicznik>1</przelicznik>
        <kod_waluty>MXN</kod_waluty>
        <kurs_sredni>0,2085</kurs_sredni>
    </pozycja>
    <pozycja>
        <nazwa_waluty>rand (Republika Poludniowej Afryki)</nazwa_waluty>
        <przelicznik>1</przelicznik>
        <kod_waluty>ZAR</kod_waluty>
        <kurs_sredni>0,2642</kurs_sredni>
    </pozycja>
    <pozycja>
        <nazwa_waluty>real (Brazylia)</nazwa_waluty>
        <przelicznik>1</przelicznik>
        <kod_waluty>BRL</kod_waluty>
        <kurs_sredni>1,1432</kurs_sredni>
    </pozycja>
    <pozycja>
        <nazwa_waluty>ringgit (Malezja)</nazwa_waluty>
        <przelicznik>1</przelicznik>
        <kod_waluty>MYR</kod_waluty>
        <kurs_sredni>0,9613</kurs_sredni>
    </pozycja>
    <pozycja>
        <nazwa_waluty>rubel rosyjski</nazwa_waluty>
        <przelicznik>1</przelicznik>
        <kod_waluty>RUB</kod_waluty>
        <kurs_sredni>0,0604</kurs_sredni>
    </pozycja>
    <pozycja>
        <nazwa_waluty>rupia indonezyjska</nazwa_waluty>
        <przelicznik>10000</przelicznik>
        <kod_waluty>IDR</kod_waluty>
        <kurs_sredni>2,9224</kurs_sredni>
    </pozycja>
    <pozycja>
        <nazwa_waluty>rupia indyjska</nazwa_waluty>
        <przelicznik>100</przelicznik>
        <kod_waluty>INR</kod_waluty>
        <kurs_sredni>5,7383</kurs_sredni>
    </pozycja>
    <pozycja>
        <nazwa_waluty>won poludniowokoreanski</nazwa_waluty>
        <przelicznik>100</przelicznik>
        <kod_waluty>KRW</kod_waluty>
        <kurs_sredni>0,3366</kurs_sredni>
    </pozycja>
    <pozycja>
        <nazwa_waluty>yuan renminbi (Chiny)</nazwa_waluty>
        <przelicznik>1</przelicznik>
        <kod_waluty>CNY</kod_waluty>
        <kurs_sredni>0,5893</kurs_sredni>
    </pozycja>
    <pozycja>
        <nazwa_waluty>SDR (MFW)</nazwa_waluty>
        <przelicznik>1</przelicznik>
        <kod_waluty>XDR</kod_waluty>
        <kurs_sredni>5,4949</kurs_sredni>
    </pozycja>
```

Comment: That's not a valid XML document - it's as simple as that. A valid XML document has *one* root element.

Comment: Everything works, Thanks for help ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, Jon Skeet answered this in the comment:

You need a root element. So you could fix this document like so:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
<pozycja>
    <nazwa_waluty>dolar amerykanski</nazwa_waluty>
    <przelicznik>1</przelicznik>
    <kod_waluty>USD</kod_waluty>
    <kurs_sredni>3,8741</kurs_sredni>
</pozycja>
<pozycja>
    <nazwa_waluty>dolar australijski</nazwa_waluty>
    <przelicznik>1</przelicznik>
    <kod_waluty>AUD</kod_waluty>
    <kurs_sredni>2,9067</kurs_sredni>
</pozycja>
<!-- and so on ... -->
</root>
```

The Wikipedia has an [article on well-formedness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-formed_document).